# element moving out of position with animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have an element that animates when hovered over, but when it seems to move out of position, when you hover, especially easy to notice after several times. I think it might possibly have something to do with the stop() function, as I am not that familiar with it.

You can view it at https://jsfiddle.net/ucaw7frL/

HTML

```
<ul><li id="home_sensors_li_temp"><h4>Temperature</h4><div class="sensor_border"></div><div class="sensors_icon"></div></li></ul>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.sensor_border').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'height':'130px',
        'width':'130px',
        'margin-left':'13px',
        'margin-top':'15px'
    })
});
$('.sensor_border').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'height':'120px',
        'width':'120px',
        'margin-left':'18px',
        'margin-top':'20px'
    })
});
```

CSS

```
body {background:blue}
.sensor_border {border:4px solid #fff; border-radius:50%; height:110px; margin:20px 18px; position:absolute; width:110px;}
.sensors_icon {height:120px; width:120px;}
```

Why is this element moving out of position, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry but what do you actually want to achieve with the stop and mouseleave?

Comment: So I want the animation to only occur whilst the mouse has entered the element, and when it leaves the element i want that mouseenter animation to stop, and then the animation for the leave to start. But if the element is entered again, during the leave animation, i want that to stop where it is, and start the enter animation again.

Comment: I want it to work exactly how it does, except NOT move out of position.

Comment: Why you don't use a simple CSS transition for this? See [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ucaw7frL/1/) :)

Comment: Because its not so browser compatible.

Comment: Is it acceptable do you think?

Comment: I don't see it moving it out of position? I just see the animation of the circle getting bigger and smaller. What browser you using?

Comment: FF, but it does move out of position, especially if u dont finish the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/qt5c6c8w/) work for you?

If I understand it correctly, the `margins` are the ones creating the *push* that you notice. But if you keep margins to a constant, set the `translate` on circle to its own center, and then animate only the `width` and `height` of the circle, I think it will produce a much better result.

***Snippet:***

```js
$('.sensor_border').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        height: 130,
        width: 130
    },{duration:400,easing:'swing'});
});
$('.sensor_border').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        height: 120,
        width: 120
    },{duration:400,easing:'swing'});
});
```

```css
body {
    background:blue
}
.sensor_border {
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    border:4px solid #fff;
    border-radius:50%;
    height:110px;
    margin:75px 73px;
    position:absolute;
    width:110px;
}
.sensors_icon {
    height:120px;
    width:120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="home_sensors_li_temp">
        <h4>Temperature</h4>
        <div class="sensor_border"></div>
        <div class="sensors_icon"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What do you think?